# Switching gears without clutch

Tags: transmission, driving

I drove manual car for a long time but never tried to switch gears without clutch.

**Question:** given that clutch-less shift is executed properly, does it take a toll on transmission in any way? For example: does clutch-less shifting reduce life of synchros?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is straightforward to do this without any wear to your synchromesh, but it takes a lot of practice, especially when downshifting as you need to match revs accurately. Learning to heel and toe correctly will help you a lot here!

You should **never** need to race the engine, as you should be using the same rev range as you would normally driving the car!

Comment: It's also worth noting that's even harder to pull this off without spousal rolling of eyes (at best).  Proper heel and toe-ing is not a procedure optimized for passenger comfort.

Comment: hahaha - very true. But the cheering from the kids in their Recaro baby seats always made up for the eye rolling :-)

Comment: You will need to blip the throttle on the downshift though, to get the engine up to the right rev range for the lower gear.

Comment: Hence the **toe** part of heel and toe, Nick

Answer (score 4):

> Question: given that clutch-less shift is executed properly, does it
>   take a toll on transmission in any way?

See [Rory's answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/4970/57): it is possible to do properly without wear.  It is difficult to do properly every time.

> For example: does clutch-less shifting reduce life of synchros?

While you are *learning* shift clutch-free, *yes*, you will beat the hell out of the synchros.

My advice is to learn how to properly [heel-and-toe](http://www.edmunds.com/how-to/heel-and-toe-downshift.html) using the clutch (and actually double clutching).  Become an expert at using the clutch properly and *then* decide whether clutchless shifting is for you.

*Full disclosure: I never shift without the clutch.  I don't drive a dog box in competition and don't see a good reason not to use one of the pedals available to me.  I've worn through the floor mat in two places trying to become better at heel and toe-ing, though.*

Comment: Yeah, even racing I still use the clutch, but heel and toe-ing speeds up the down changes:-)

Answer (score 1):

I had an old T5 I could shift beautifully without the clutch but the motor had to be screaming (somewhere between 4 and 5 grand). At normal operating speeds the transition just wasn't fast enough and the gears would grind.

I've never seen a tranny that would tolerate clutchless shifting under regular conditions without some major gear crunching.

Comment: 4-5k is normal operating speeds for many engines ;) That's nicely in the power band on mine (redline is 7k, and it's gutless below 2k5)

Comment: Mine was a V8 so those pistons were hanging on for dear life at 5 and hoping not to meet the valves!